# Array within in clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have several sqls that I am running as part of a large db script. There are often conditions which are repeated over several of the sqls. For example

```
update phone_numbers set num = 'abc' where id not in (1,2,4,5,6,8);
update fax_numbers set num = 'abc' where id not in (1,2,4,5,6,8);
update email_add set val = 'abc' where id not in (1,2,4,5,6,8);
```

My problem is that I am constantly repeating the values in the not in clause.

how can i move these numbes into a variable and then apply to each sql. Something like

```
my_var = (1,2,4,5,6,8);
update phone_numbers set num = 'abc' where id not in @my_var;
update fax_numbers set num = 'abc' where id not in @my_var;
update email_add set val = 'abc' where id not in @my_var;
```

The SQL is running on Oracle if that helps? Ive done this before with one parameter but not with an array.

Ive seen this [Oracle PL/SQL - How to create a simple array variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012625/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-create-a-simple-array-variable) but that doesnt apply to an in

Ive searched a few places but nothing seems to be quite what I want

Thanks

Comment: Where are you running the code from - just a client, like SQL Developer or SQL\*Plus? And if so which client?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Is is via SQL plus or SQL developer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, you could define a substitution variable:

```
define my_var = '1,2,4,5,6,8'
update phone_numbers set num = 'abc' where id not in (&my_var);
update fax_numbers set num = 'abc' where id not in (&my_var);
update email_add set val = 'abc' where id not in (&my_var);
```

Each statement will do a simple substitution of the value (as the name suggests); if you have `set verify on` then you'd see that happening:

```
old:update phone_numbers set num = 'abc' where id not in (&my_var)
new:update phone_numbers set num = 'abc' where id not in (1,2,4,5,6,8)
```

You could also wrap your statements in a PL/SQL block and use [a built-in collection type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/ext_types_ref.htm#ADDCI4964) to hold the values:

```
declare
  my_var sys.odcinumberlist;
begin
  my_var := sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,4,5,6,8);

  update phone_numbers set num = 'abc'
  where id not in (select column_value from table (my_var));
  update fax_numbers set num = 'abc'
  where id not in (select column_value from table (my_var));
  update email_add set val = 'abc'
  where id not in (select column_value from table (my_var));
end;
/
```

... which is longer and hides update counts unless you display SQL%ROWCOUNT yourself, but would work from any client.

Because this is using a varray type you can use collection methods. So if you currently had something like this in a PL/SQL block::

```
if x in (1,2,4,5,6,8) then
```

you could instead do;

```
if my_var.exists(x) the
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex-poole. I have got it sort of working. The substition bit didnt seem to work for some reason. It sill opened  a popup asking me to input data. I tried the built in collection type and that worked for most of them apart from whne I was using the condition within an if. I then had to duplicate the ids for the if statement :(

Comment: @RNJ - you shouldn't get a pop-up if you've run the `define` part. At least, running as a script, and in a recent version. Not sure what you mean about 'if' though, can you show an example?

Comment: yep the define should work - Ive looked at other sites as well. not sure what is happening. THe if statement doesnt allow a subselect clause and with the collection type because it is doing a select from table(..) then I think it sees it as a sub select

Comment: @RNJ - if I understand what you're doing, say, the equivalent of `if x in (&my_var) then` (if define worked!), you can use the collection method:  `if my_var.exists(x) then`. (Added that to my answer). Not sure why define doesn't work though; are you using a really old version of SQL Devleoper? Either will work in SQL\*Plus too.