# PL/SQL maximum size of VARRAY

Tags: oracle, plsql, size, database-administration, varray

I'm trying to figure out the possible **upper bound** of VARRAY in PL/SQL.

We sure can define VARRAY type as

```
TYPE type_name IS {VARRAY | VARYING ARRAY} (size_limit) 
   OF element_type [NOT NULL];
```

Oracle documentation has this to say:

> Each varray is stored as a single object, either inside the table of
>   which it is a column (if the varray is less than 4KB) or outside the
>   table but still in the same tablespace (if the varray is greater than
>   4KB). You must update or retrieve all elements of the varray at the
>   same time, which is most appropriate when performing some operation on
>   all the elements at once. But you might find it impractical to store
>   and retrieve large numbers of elements this way.

But what is the upper bound of `size_limit` parameter? Is it equal to unsigned integer (4,294,967,295)?

Comment: Surely for any limit much greater than single digits, there is a diminishing benefit to declaring a limit at all. If the intention is to have one array element per US state, for example, it would be reasonable to declare a `varray(50) of varchar2(2)`. But _2 billion_?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within PL/SQL the limit is 2147483647. The same limit applies to schema varying array types.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE t IS VARRAY(2147483647) OF NUMBER;
BEGIN
    NULL;
END;
```

If you increase it it throws `PLS-00325: non-integral numeric literal 2147483648 is inappropriate in this context`.

Comment: Do you think PL/SQL has special constant for that value?

Comment: I'm not aware about any specific keyword for it. Some built-in packages defines this value regular way using `my_constant CONSTANT NUMBER := 2147483647;`