# How to write an array literal in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to use an array literal in Oracle, such as:

```
SELECT [1,2,3] FROM dual
# [1,2,3] -- int[]
```

Or:

```
SELECT ([1,2,3])[0] FROM dual
# 1 -- int
```

Or what's the simplest (i.e., possible not in PL/SQL?) way to do this?

Comment: What is wrong with  select 1,2,3 from dual?  What are you trying to do with the results?  what is going to call this select statement?  Short answer, no.

Comment: @OldProgrammer just playing around with array notation within a scalar... and seeing what Oracle supports compared to some other DBs.

Comment: There is no such construct in oracle sql.

Comment: you can define an array typr, but izt behaves dieffently

Comment: @nbk how would that be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012625/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-create-a-simple-array-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanta flexible list, y an use a type like this

> ```
> create type t_inttable as table of int
> /
> ```

> ```
> create table tab_mydata (
>   id         number(10),
>   intlist   t_inttable
> )
> nested table intlist store as ntab_intlist
> ```

> ```
> insert into tab_mydata values(
>   1, 
>   t_inttable(1,2,3)
> )
> /
> ```

> ```
> select * from tab_mydata
> /
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | INTLIST
> -: | :------
> ```

> ```
> select t.id, x.column_value from tab_mydata t, table(intlist) x
> /
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | COLUMN_VALUE
> -: | -----------:
>  1 |            1
>  1 |            2
>  1 |            3
> ```

> ```
> select t.id, x.column_value from tab_mydata t, table(intlist) x
> where x.column_value like 3
> /
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | COLUMN_VALUE
> -: | -----------:
>  1 |            3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46868a5fb7dd6cfb8f4a8516d2868225)*