# oracle function return array of varchars, in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I've to use an oracle function that returns an array of strings in a c# webapi. I don't realy have an idea on how to do this. I've started with the following code:

```
using (var cmd = _connection.CreateCommand()) 
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    //dual is temporary table where data is stored?!
    cmd.CommandText = "select Test_mp.f_loten(:p_item)  from dual";
    var p = cmd.Parameters;
    p.Add("p_item", 12942);
    _connection.Open();
    var rd= await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961908/select-from-plsql-associative-array

Comment: An example with an array as an input parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605713/calling-an-oracle-procedure-with-a-pl-sql-collection-type-parameter-via-net

Comment: Oracle's documentation for passing arrays using C# ODP.NET http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17odp-093600.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my return type which was a custom Oracle type.